# Communicate with bluetooth module from Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I'm trying to get my bluetooth module into [command mode](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/rn-bluetooth-um.pdf). I have [pin 0(RX)](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/rn-42-ds.pdf) on the Uno connected to the [UART_TX pin](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/rn-42-ds.pdf) on the bluetooth module, and pin 1(TX) on the Uno connected to the UART_RX pin on the bluetooth module.

Heres the sketch thats running on the Uno.

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);   // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  Serial.flush();
  //enter command mode
  Serial.println("$$$");
}

void loop() {
  // send data only when you receive data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    //read the incoming byte:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    //say what you got:
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
  }
}
```

This is what I see on the Serial Monitor

> $$$

I expected to see

> $$$
>   I received: C
>   I received: M
>   I received: D

What am I doing wrong? Or if its not supposed to do what I expected, what am I not understanding correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is that you can't both talk to a device on the UART and talk to a terminal (your computer) at the same time using the same pins (0 and 1) of the Arduino. If you want to talk to your computer as well as a device you have to use a [SoftSerial](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) library (or [NewSoftSerial](http://sundial.org/arduino/index.php/newsoftserial/)) and wire the device to use different pins rather than the hardware UART...

<strike>That being said, it seems plausible that the bluetooth module is prompting your for a command with the message "CMD".</strike> (misread question, this was what you expected, not what actually happened)

Comment: Ah, I think I remember running across someone mentioning that elsewhere,